# Local users access SQL Server correctly, but domain users don't return all the data

Tags: sql-server

We have just changed from a workgroup to a domain running SBS 2012 and SQL Server 2008R2. The problem I have is when logged in as a domain user my application connects to the server but only returns some of the data.

If I use the same computer and log in as the old local user (same user name and password as the domain account) it works fine.

I have added the domain user name as sysadmin in SQL Server and it still only returns some of the data. I know the obvious answer is just to use the local accounts but then we wont be able to use the exchange email and other functions in the domain.

I have tried everything I can think of and spent 3 days searching through SQL forums and found no answer yet.

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to why the data is subsetted? Does it provide consistent, if incorrect, results? You *are* running the same query against the same database, right? Have you fully qualified your tables' schemas? I could see something like localuser.Table1 and domainuser.Table1 existing with different data in there and if your default schema is set to each of those, then a lazy query of `select * from Table1` would yield the "wrong" results.

Comment: Also, how are you evaluating your result set? Through SSMS? Custom application? Some other management interface?

Comment: billinkc, that may well be the problem, I have no access to the application code to check, unfortunately the developer who wrote the application passed away 2 years ago and the code died with him. Is there any other way of checking?

Comment: Have you tried using the domain accounts to query from SSMS?

Comment: This query would determine whether there are any tables with the same name in different schemas `SELECT T.* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T INNER JOIN ( SELECT T.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T GROUP BY T.TABLE_NAME HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 ) DUPE(table_name) ON DUPE.table_name = T.TABLE_NAME`